# Transition on background-size doesn't work

Tags: css, css-transitions, background-size

I'm trying to put a transition on my background-image on hover.
This is my Code so far:

HTML

```
<div class="item-one"></div>
```

CSS

```
.item-one { 
    height: 345px;
    width: 256px;    
    background: url('http://placehold.it/256x345') scroll no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 1500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-size 1500 linear;
    -o-transition: background-size 1500 linear
    -ms-transition: background-size 1500ms linear;
    transition: background-size 1500ms linear;
}

.item-one:hover {
    background-size: 150%;  
}
```

[See JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ukfnwxm9/)

But this doesn't work for me, tested in different browsers. Other transitions like background-color work as expected. Is there any restriction for transitions on this property?

Comment: also as @fsn mentioned, you have missing semicolon on 8 line

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think the problem is with `background-size: cover`, when you change it to

```
background-size: 100%;
```

it will work

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukfnwxm9/2/)

There is some other question about `background-size: cover` alternative, that can help [Is there an alternative to background-size:cover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501126/is-there-an-alternative-to-background-sizecover)

Or some different solution for problems like this:
[CSS3 crossfade bg image when cover is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276459/css3-crossfade-bg-image-when-cover-is-used)

Comment: It seems this doesn't work in Chrome, which is why I thought my own project wasn't working, along with your JS Fiddle link. Firefox makes it show fine, but Chrome shows no transition

Comment: If you want it to work with Chrome you need to give both parameters. Like that `background-size:100% 100%;`

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo:

```
.item-one { 
...
-o-transition: background-size 1500 linear
...
}
```

---

working version below:

```
.item-one {
    background-size: 50%;
    webkit-transition: background-size 1500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-size 1500 linear;
    -o-transition: background-size 1500 linear;
    -ms-transition: background-size 1500ms linear;
    transition: background-size 1500ms linear;
}

.item-one:hover {
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

works fine, it didn't wokred before cuz of 'background-size:cover' :

```
    **‘cover’:**

    Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic 
    aspect ratio (if any), to the smallest size such 
    that both its width and its height can completely
    cover the background positioning area.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using transform: scale(150%) for the item-one and the container set the specific size and overflow: hidden;

```
<div class=container>
  <div class="item-one"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
 .container {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .item-one:hover {
   transform: scale(150%);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You have to set background-size: 100%;  if you want to get transition of 108% on hover.